# Laravel Eloquent Relationships Many To Many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a program that defines a model called a Production line and this production line produces a product. The production line also has many inputs to produce this product so this production line has many production lines. I was able to connect this relationship with no problem in the model itself. A one-to-many referring to itself in this way

```
class ProductionLine extends Model {

  ...

  /**
   * The inputs for this production line
   */
  public function productionLines() {
    return $this->hasMany(ProductionLine::class);
  }

  /**
   * The consumer
   */
  public function productionLine() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductionLine::class);
  }
}
```

But I was thinking about what if the production line has many consumers. How would I setup this kind of relationship?
Would I just simply have in the ProductionLine model the following?

```
public function productionLines() {
 return $this->belongsToMany(ProductionLine::class);
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for belongsToMany https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Yeah but this is the same model. I understand the belongsToMany to setup a many to many between two models but I have only one model

Comment: Also you can implement relation hasManyThrough https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: could you, update the question with your database structure? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Why would you need my database structure? Do you mean my migration? This is a concept. If you have one model is it possible to connect a many to many relationship with itself.

Comment: There is only one model. A many to many through is a three model setup. wtf

Answer (score 0):

Add another relation like this in your Production line Model.

```
public function consumer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Consumer');
}
```

Just remember Consumer table must have a prod_id denoting which production line it belongs to

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent allows you to define the pivot table and the ids in this table which proved to be quite useful.

My model was called ProductionLine and a production line has many consumers and producers but both the consumer and producer were also production lines.

SO how do you do that?

In the model I defined my own custom ids and the pivot table 'consumer_producer'.

```
public function producerProductionLines() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(ProductionLine::class, 'consumer_producer',
    'consumer_production_line_id', 'producer_production_line_id');
}

public function consumerProductionLines() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(ProductionLine::class, 'consumer_producer',
    'producer_production_line_id', 'consumer_production_line_id');
}
```

For the migration I created my own

```
php artisan:make migration ConsumerProducer
```

When the migration was created I added my custom pivot table name with the two custom ids.

```
public function up() {
  Schema::create('consumer_producer', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('consumer_production_line_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('producer_production_line_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

And that's it! This only works if you defined the ids differently otherwise both columns would be the same name and that can't work.